# Failed to pull image "registry.connect.redhat.com/gitlab/gitlab-runner@sha256

Tags: openshift, gitlab-ci-runner, redhat-containers

Go this on Openshift 4.11 running a gitlab-runner/certified, community is fine but not good for production.  I only found one related link online about the error

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29470

Unfortunately there's no solution on that link.

I subscribe trial to redhat.io and got a registry login.  Created secret for docker and make it default pull.  But to no luck on the registry.connect.redhat.com/gitlab/gitlab-runner is nowhere to find.  I can pull manually the proxy registry.redhat.io/openshift4/ose-kube-rbac-proxy with no problem and not registry.connect.redhat.com/gitlab/gitlab-runner-operator but the gitlab-manager pod is running anyway so I think there's no problem on the operator.

I troubleshoot using,
https://access.redhat.com/articles/3560571

I got this,
~/tmp$ curl -u $TOKENID:$SECRET "https://sso.redhat.com/auth/realms/rhcc/protocol/redhat-docker-v2/auth?service=docker-registry&client_id=curl&scope=repository:rhel:pull"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Connection
curl: (3)  malformed
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: to
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: host
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: left
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: intact
curl: (3) Port number ended with ','
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"Please login to the Red Hat Registry using your Customer Portal credentials. Further instructions can be found here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/3399531","detail":[{"type":"repository","name":"rhel","actions":["pull"]}]}]}

Is there problem with redhat container?

Answer (score 0):

I test v4.10, it work on it but on that time, I put it in the openshift-operators NS.    I add cert-manager like in v4.11 first.

Comment: The image on 4.10 is this registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/ci-cd/gitlab-runner-ubi-images/gitlab-runner-helper-ocp, while on 4.11 is this https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/gitlab/gitlab-runner/5ea0a90eecb5246c0903b9fd?container-tabs=overview&tag=latest&push_date=1629228268000 and I can't pull it.